# ftp push changed files to server

Tags: linux, search, ubuntu, ftp, automation

Is there an easy way for me to automatically search "recursively" through a directory and put changed files up through ftp to my live server in their correct spots?

CLI is ideally what I'm looking for.

I'm tired of manually searching out the files I need to do and doing it individually or by queue, trying to make this quick and painless

Comment: You want the NCFTPClient. Or OpenSSH.

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server is under your control, you might want to try [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) instead of FTP.

Answer (score 2):

rsync is the way to go for keeping directories balanced. +1 for Frederic.

The other way to go is change management, like Subversion. Once you set it up, files checked in over time can be brought to productions with a simple "svn up" command.

Subversion: http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads